# Firebase Deploy Problem: Not in a firebase app directory

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1Hjy.png)

Error: Not in a Firebase app directory(could not locate firebase.json)

Answer (score 4):

Run `firebase login` and `firebase init` first to initialize the file `firebase.json`.

Also, run `firebase deploy` inside the root directory of the project folder where `firebase.json` lives..